# Normalizing Categorical data

Tags: categorical-data, normalization, continuous-data

I want to compare 2 datasets. The first is categorical data on a 4 point scale: 1-4. The second dataset has continuous data that has been normalized (raw scores on a 0-100 scale, subtract the respondent’s mean score across items and divide by their standard deviation across items). These two datasets measure the same thing, personality, so I want to compare scores between them. What's the best way to normalize a categorical variable in order to compare between these scores?

Comment: Why do you assume "normalization" is needed at all?  That wouldn't seem to accomplish anything towards helping in the comparison--except for obscuring any inherent meaning or interpretation of the data.

Comment: I agree with Whuber, your data simply differs in precision. I'd want to know more about the framing of the questions about personality to see if the data even can be meaningfully compared.

Comment: If they measure the same thing, then the ordinal data should be something like a quantized version of the continuous data. You could equate CDFs to assign to each category a corresponding interval of the score. To "compare" the two, I think you would need to then use some other variable. For example if you have 2 samples from different geographic areas, see if the quantized interval-bounds are different or the same.